# Can't get capture group from String.match() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I was trying to match a simple string with a simple `RegExp`, like this

```
let html = '<td>Amount</td><td>23</td>';
let rx = /<td>Amount<\/td><td>(.*)<\/td>/gi;
console.log(html.match(rx));
```

I got

```
[ '<td>Amount</td><td>23</td>' ]
```

instead of the expected

```
[
  '<td>Amount</td><td>23</td>',
  '23',
  index: 0,
  input: '<td>Amount</td><td>23</td>',
  groups: undefined
]
```

I can't find a simple and straight forward answer for this on StackOverflow.

Why do I get the entire string instead of the capturing group in the result?

Comment: Note: [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) works with a `g` flag

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, using the modifier `/g` with `.match()` will return the entire string instead of the capturing groups.

So simply removing `g` from the RegEx did the trick:

```
let rx = /<td>Amount<\/td><td>(.*)<\/td>/i;
```

Comment: the .* in your capture group is greedy. if you change it to .*? you should see better results as it should stop at the first <\/td> match.
let rx = /<td>Amount<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td>/i;